# is Pouchdb production ready and robust for processing thousands of documents

Tags: architecture, couchdb, replication, synchronization, pouchdb

currently working on a project that requires huge amount of data entry, document update almost every minute of the day. i am considering using Pouchdb as offline storage for this app although each local copy of Pouchdb will be in live sync with Remote online Couchdb server. i want to know the following:

1. the database size can grow to as big as hundreds of thousands, currently over 60,000 documents.
2. is Pouchdb the right solution for this kind of system.
3. is Pouchdb robust enough to handle CRUD on a local db that has over 60K documents and will continue to grow everyday at rate of over 1,000 documents.
4. What are the ways to reduce document conflicts since each app installation will have its own local Pouchdb and how can i speed up sync?
5. how reliable will Pouchdb replication be given that a lot of document creation, read, sync and edit will be going on at each end.
6. currently at an office, all the current installation of the app, syncs to a local couchdb, but it is slow and takes time before all the local copies are in sync and there are chances that document conflict can/or will occur.

There are close to 50 installations in same wired LAN as the Couchdb server, should they make direct calls to the LAN Couchdb server or to local Pouchdb copy.

You opinion and answers will be very very helpful.

Comment: Is not for my taste, replication is too slow with thousand of docs. it has several issues, the same with the plugins, i wasted like 50% of the project time fixing bugs, i had redesign several times the logic because it doesn't work with large amount of data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, it probably depends on your target platform. PouchDB has no upper document limit, but browsers [definitely have storage limits](http://pouchdb.com/faq.html#data_limits).

Second, if documents are being modified/deleted a lot, you will probably want to look into [compaction](http://pouchdb.com/api.html#compaction). You may even want to use [filter-pouch](https://github.com/nolanlawson/filter-pouch) to compress the document fields with gzip before storing them.

Third, CouchDB replication currently has some performance problems due to HTTP chattiness. There's [some advice here](http://pouchdb.com/2014/08/29/pouchdb-3.0.3.html) about how you can improve the sync performance. We're also working on [an alternative replication method](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-replication-stream) to speed it up.

Conflicts are a larger question; we have a guide coming out soon that will have a whole chapter on conflict resolution. But if you're impatient, basically it's the same as CouchDB, and they have docs about it. :)

One last comment: if the CouchDB is literally hosted on the same LAN as the devices you are targeting, and if you are certain that the devices will only be used while online, then probably PouchDB will offer no performance benefits. But you may want to use PouchDB as a simple direct CouchDB client, just to keep your code flexible.

Comment: thanks so much, then i forgot to mention, is there a way to call a query with design document using Pouchdb on Chrome app which does not allow eval()

Comment: Yes, this may work in 95% of your cases: https://github.com/evidenceprime/pouchdb.mapreduce.noeval

Comment: This is an old question. But by 'use PouchDB as a simple direct CouchDB client', do mean we can configure pouchdb to use remote couchDB as an adapter instead of indexDB? Is there a way to achieve that?